# Debug javascript and at the same time examining html and css changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, debugging

Hi can one debug scripts so that I can see html(maybe css) behaviors at the same time. for example when I would want to change the class of the tag from javascript and I have to navigate from debugger tab to inspector(in Firefox) tab and to check html(sometimes it is really long) and see if change happened. Can I do so that I can debug javascript and see html changes synchronously as I step in the lines of code.

Comment: in chrome you can open both the elements and the console together, not sure about firebug

Answer (score 0):

I created a new tool that allows you to visualize your HTML / CSS layout just by moving the mouse.  You can easily view the layout of your elements after making these changes.

[HTML Box Visualizer - GitHub](https://github.com/ghmcadams/boxvis)